# processing fee on stripe on $0 susbcription

Tags: stripe-payments

Stripe processing fee is 2.9%+30c as per the [docs](https://stripe.com/us/pricing). I have 3 subscription plans $20, $10 and $0. That $0 means those are free subscription.

Whenever a user sign up to the site she can choose any subscription plan and upgrade/downgrade at any time.

So what happens on stripe fee if a user always use free $0 subscription?

Answer (score 2):

**My answer is based on previous testing**

No fee will occur as there won't be any **charge** happen in Stripe for $0 Plan.

But what happen in Stripe in background?

- Will create a new invoice (Event `invoice.created`)
- Mark the invoice as paid (Event `invoice.payment_succeeded`)
- If it is first time I mean subscription created then Customer subscribed (Event `customer.subscription.created`)